# Loop stops all code after one iteration

Tags: c#, loops

I have a loop which in theory should loop 40000 times but exits and doesn't continue with code after the loop, just after one iteration. I figured that I wasnt being a silly willy about the for-loops since it didn't continue after the loops at all, so that might be something with restrictions for Lists? Or mayby something about the VS-debugger that isn't working preperly? (probably not tho...)
**Edit**: Thanks for pointing out that the last layer was pointless. I edited the code, but the problem persists.
**Edit2**: To clarify, the code does not result in an exception, or breaks. It just stops without any notifications, and shows the form(since I do a windows forms application). Just... it just don't want to continue and skips the rest of the code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < hiddenLayerDepth - 1; i++)
{
    Connectors.Add(new List<List<List<List<Connector>>>>());
    for (int j = 0; j < playfieldSize; j++)
    {
        Connectors[i].Add(new List<List<List<Connector>>>());
        for (int k = 0; k < playfieldSize; k++)
        {
            Connectors[i][j].Add(new List<List<Connector>>());
            for (int l = 0; l < playfieldSize; l++)
            {
                Connectors[i][j][k][l].Add(new Connector());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`hiddenLayerDepth` is set to 5 when entering the loop, and `playfieldSize` is set to 10. It enters the innermost loop and executes the code inside, then it just stops without increasing `m`.

Comment: do you have a try catch statement higher in the hierarchy call that just swallows an exception which could happen in your code here ? (wrong indexing for instance) Also, pay close attention to your Output - debug window in VS

Comment: If nothing else, you appear to be missing the use of the 'L' loop.

Comment: Defines "stops"? Crashes? Exception? Continues in on of the other loops? And in general commentary: A 4D list/array? Nope, that needs refactoring.,.

Comment: Check the Thrown checkbox at the Common Language Runtime Exceptions. You can find it at Debug/Exceptions in Visual Studio. It might show you an exception, which is than being catched later, so you couldn't see before.

Answer (score 1):

Missing

```
Connectors[i][j][k].Add(new List<List<Connector>>());
```

If you know the sizes you should just create and array up front

Answer (score -1):

Well, I tried to add a 'Connector' where there were no list. The List that contained the lists that would countain the Connectors was not added.